# Sorting not working after filtering by text

Tags: bug, old-teams

Search sorting is not working after doing this steps:

1. Click on "members" to sort by members count
2. Type "sample text" on "Type to find teams" input area
3. Remove what you typed on "Type to find teams" input area

=> Sort by members count is not working anymore, the result is sorted by creation date.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. We'll look into it.